# Macro for Auto fit height

Tags: excel, excel-template, vba

I have thousands or row in excel. I want macro which will auto-fit my row. One particular cell in row may have variable length of data. so that row should occupy space accoutering to line of data in one particular cell in that row.

I have tried using

```
.Rows.WrapText = True
.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

but its not working.

can anyone help me with this??

Comment: `Cells.Rows.WrapText = True: Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit` works for me...

Comment: I see that you have `DOT` before the `Rows/Cells` Can you paste the complete code?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: but it is not working in my case :(

Comment: For Each worksht In workbook.Worksheets worksht.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

Comment: Do you have merged cells in any row?

Comment: Also add .cells before .rows and try again...

Comment: For WrapText right??? Not working... :(

Comment: I do have merge cell in my report, but in that case it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Cells.Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

Comment: I want height to be autoresized not width. :(